# Pressing fragment invoke button multiple times issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a main activity which has a frame and two buttons. Clicking on each button displays a fragment.

App Image：

[image]

Code:

```
package com.example.activitylifecycle

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val firstFragment = FirstFragment()
        val secondFragment = SecondFragment()

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.flFragment, firstFragment)
            commit()
        }

        val btnFragmentOne = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnFragment1)
        val btnFragmentTwo = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnFragment2)

        btnFragmentOne.setOnClickListener {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                replace(R.id.flFragment, firstFragment)
                addToBackStack(null)
                commit()
            }
        }

        btnFragmentTwo.setOnClickListener {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                replace(R.id.flFragment, secondFragment)
                addToBackStack(null)
                commit()
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am using addToBackStack() function to make sure that when someone has pressed the fragment2 button and after that they press back button the fragment1 is shown. It's working perfectly.

But when I press the fragment2 button 5 times. I have to press back button 5 times to get to fragment1.

How can I check if the fragment is already in the stack before adding it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way, that before creating some kind of fragment it is better to check if this fragment is active and visible on the screen. If it is active, a new fragment of that class will not be created. That may solve your problem

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val firstFragment = FirstFragment()
    val secondFragment = SecondFragment()

    //First Fragment class name entered as Tag
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.flFragment, firstFragment, firstFragment.javaClass.name)
        commit()
    }

    val btnFragmentOne = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnFragment1)
    val btnFragmentTwo = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnFragment2)

    btnFragmentOne.setOnClickListener {
        val fragment1 =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FirstFragment::class.java.name) as FirstFragment?
        // Checking is First Fragment is not active
        if (!(fragment1 != null && fragment1.isVisible)) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                //First Fragment class name entered as Tag
                replace(R.id.flFragment, firstFragment, firstFragment.javaClass.name)
                addToBackStack(null)
                commit()
            }
        }

    }

    btnFragmentTwo.setOnClickListener {
        val fragment2 =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(SecondFragment::class.java.name) as SecondFragment?
        // Checking is Second Fragment is not active
        if (!(fragment2 != null && fragment2.isVisible)) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                //Second Fragment class name entered as Tag
                replace(R.id.flFragment, secondFragment, secondFragment.javaClass.name)
                addToBackStack(null)
                commit()
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Hope that will help to you

Answer (score 0):

When you add it to the stack, it gets added everytime you press the button.

So if you press fragment2button 5 times, it gets added 5 times to the stack, and you need to press backbutton 5 times to remove all 5 of those from the stack and get back to fragment1

You need to edit the code such that if the fragment already exists, then it shouldn't be added to the stack again

Comment: You have not provided the solution.

Comment: the OP didnt ask for a solution, so I told the OP what was going wrong in the code
if they wish to know the solution as well, i would be happy to provide it, i feel they can try it out with the new logic before they ask for the solution directly